# Regular expression to ignore white space from html tag content

Tags: c#, html, regex

I have a string which contains a link that looks like this:

```
string source = "<img src='ftp://c//hafiz hussain//appdata//images//image.bmp' />"
```

I used the following regex to remove the `src` content:

```
string regexSrc = @"<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"" >]+?)[ '""][^>]*?>";
MatchCollection matchesImgSrc = Regex.Matches(source , regexSrc, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

This is working fine, only if the folder name has no spaces. For the above case the `matchesImgSrc[1].Groups[1].Value` matches only till 'ftp://c//hafiz'

Content after the whitespace is ignored.

Comment: remove th space from the char class. And it's better to use an html parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<img[^>]*?src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"">]+?)['""][^>]*?>
```

You can try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/mT0iE7/22

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have an XML-compliant HTML. Thus, I'd suggest using `XElement` to do that task.

```
var source = "<img src='ftp://c//hafiz hussain//appdata//images//image.bmp' />";
var elt2 = XElement.Parse(source);
var imgs = elt2.DescendantsAndSelf("img");
foreach (var im in imgs)
{
    var att = im.Attributes().Where(p => p.Name.LocalName.ToLower() == "src");
    if (att != null)
    {
       im.SetAttributeValue("src", string.Empty);
    }
}
// Converting back to string to see the result
var resst = elt2.ToString();
```

Output:

[image]

A regex solution can be used as a fallback:

```
var source = "<img src='ftp://c//hafiz hussain//appdata//images//image.bmp' />";
var regexSrc = @"(?<=<img[^>]*?)src\s*=\s*[""']?([^'"">]+)[ '""](?=[^>]*?>)";
var reslt = Regex.Replace(source, regexSrc, "src=\"\"");
```

Output: `<img src="" />`

Comment: If I were you I'd use the solution based on `XElement` as the main one, and the regex solution only in case of improper/invalid XML.